# Apache Thrift polymorphism

Tags: java, thrift

I need to have three thrift classes: **ThriftClassList**, **ThriftClass1**, **ThriftClass2**. Depending on some conditions from request I need to pass to **ThriftClassList** object of class **ThriftClass1** or **ThriftClass2**.

So I need to have some sort of such thrift definition

```
struct ThriftClassList {
    1: required list<?> data
}
```

But thrift doesn't support such definition, I can only do

```
struct ThriftClass1List {
    1: required list<ThriftClass1> data
}

struct ThriftClass2List {
    1: required list<ThriftClass2> data
}
```

But I don't want to have two four classes, ThriftClass1List and ThriftClass2List are similar, I want to have some sort of wildcard.

Is doing two list classes the only way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in way to do this with Thrift. Regarding this restriction it may help to keep in mind that Thrift generates code for about 20+ languages. Not all of them do support OOP or comparable concepts, let alone polymorphism or more enhanced concepts like generics.

A possible solution could involve `union`s:

```
struct ListElement {
    1: Foo foo  
    2: Bar bar  
    // add other elements as needed
}

struct OuterClass {
    1: list<ListElement> data
}
```

The only drawback here is that nothing prevents you from mixing foo and bar in one list instance. If such must be avoided, either add code to verify this at runtime, or define two different lists as you already did in the original question to make it type safe from the beginning. The choice is yours.

Comment: It's a mixing, and it breaks Single Responsibility principle.

Comment: Nobody forces you to do it this way if your belief system says otherwise. Thanks for the downvote on an entirely correct answer that you just do not like because of arguments that do not really apply.

Comment: @Johannes Martinsson: If someone else (for sure not the OP) wants a list with only one element type then `list<elementtype>` will suffice. No need for anything more complex. Putting the two lists into the inner misses the point about why we use that `union` here in the first place. Finally, wrapping that construct into another `Outer` is nonsense - the latter does not add any value anymore. Bottom line? If you think you have a better answer, please add one below. But stop trying to [verschlimmbessern](http://www.dict.cc/german-english/verschlimmbessern.html) other people's answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @JensG answer. Another option for "polymorphism" is to just have every type as optional and use a flag field to indicate which are there.

```
enum PersonType {
  CHILD,
  ADULT,
  EMPLOYEE,
  BOSS,
  DOCTOR
}

struct Person {
  1: i32 personId , 
  2: PersonType type, // Tells us which are set
  3: double timestamp,
  4: optional Child child
  5: optional Adult adult
  6: optional Employee employee
  7: optional Boss boss
  8: optional Doctor doctor
}

service API{
  Person GetPerson(1: i32 id)
}
```

then client side you have a factory:

```
func getPerson(int id) *Person {

  p := thrift.GetPerson(1)
  switch p.type {
    case thrift.CHILD:
      return newChild(p)
    case thrift.ADULT:
      return newAdult(p)
    case thrift.BOSS:
      panic("Not a person")
  } 
}
```

Comment: A `union` could also be an alternative (but watch out for [THRIFT-3650](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-3650))

Comment: As the example code would betray, my usecase is mostly golang. As well that ticket has been "resolved" so may not be a long term issue.